# Wordpress: How to unescape the results when using $wpdb->get_results?

Tags: php, wordpress, escaping

To add a new rows to the database I use `$wpdb->insert`, and to get the rows I use `$wpdb->get_results`.

The problem is that `$wpdb->insert` seems to be escaping the input. For example, `a"b` is saved as `a\"b` in the database. But, `$wpdb->get_results` doesn't seem to unescape back `a\"b` to `a"b`.

Is this the correct behavior by design?

Should I unescape the result of `$wpdb->get_results` manually? (What is the proper function for this?)

Answer (score 6):

`$wpdb->insert()` and `$wpdb->prepare()` will escape data to prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The `$wpdb->get_results()` function is designed to work generically with SQL `SELECT` statements, so I believe the fact that the slashes are left in place is intentional.  This allows the consumer of the data to process it as necessary.

Since the `$wpdb->get_results()` funciton returns an array of `stdClass` objects, in order to remove the slashes in all columns in every row, you must iterate through the rows, and through the properties of each row object running the PHP `stripslashes()` function on it.

```
foreach( $quotes as &$quote ) {
    foreach( $quote as &$field ) {
        if ( is_string( $field ) )
            $field = stripslashes( $field );
    }
}
```

More information on the wpdb->get_results() function:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

Answer (score 2):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep

```
//replace $_POST with $POST
    $POST      = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
    $wpdb->insert( 
            'wp_mytable', 
            array( 
                'field_name'        => $POST['field_name'], 
                'type'              => $POST['type'],
                'values'            => serialize($POST['values']),
                'unanswered_link'   => $POST['unanswered_link'], 
            ), 
            array( 
                '%s','%s','%s','%s'
            ) 
        );
```